# Gedit F9 side pane shortcut is not working

Tags: gedit

I am using gedit for some editing and when I use F9 in order to make side pane visible or invisible my display is just getting dim and nothing happens.

Comment: I had the same problem using f9 for toggling status notifications. Perhaps we should change the title to "F9 is dimming screen" or something to make this more generic so that others will find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have widget layer turned on and  mapped to F9 in Compiz Config

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your keyboard has the brightness adjustment bound to `Fn-F9`. Are you sure your `Fn` key is not stuck? Maybe your keyboard has a Fn-Lock mode, similar to Num-Lock, and you enabled it by accident?